# Wireless adapter stopped working on Xubuntu after upgrade

Tags: drivers, wireless, xubuntu

Been using Xubuntu 16.04 with D Link DWA 182D1 (wireless adapter). Switched to Xubuntu 22.04.03, and the adapter stopped working.
I can see the adapter, and the network, it asks for password but the connection is never established after that.
I can see the attempts to connect on the network manager, but no trace of em on the router.
There are multiple other devices connected to the network, meaning I know it's working correctly.
Installed a lot of drivers, it didn't help, but it's possible I did something wrong.
Any help is greatly appreciated and much needed.

Comment: You mention really old Xubuntu 16.04 LTS (*without clues as to what kernel stack you were using; LTS releases have kernel stack options which are decided by default by install media used for flavors like Xubuntu*). I assume you re-installed Xubuntu 22.04.3 LTS media (*thus are using the HWE kernel stack; ie. 6.2 kernel*). I'd likely try the GA kernel stack for 22.04 (ie. 5.15, which will be closer to 16.04's 4.5 (GA) or 4.15 (HWE) using *live* media first. You mention installing *drivers* but gave no details? What did you try? other kernel stacks? (thus different modules/drivers) or what?

Comment: Unfortunately don't know anymore which kernel stack I had, other that it was the one that came by default with installation, haven't changed a thing. Now I'm indeed running 6.2 kernel. As for drivers, chose "install all drivers" option during installation and then when it didn't do the trick additionally installed rtl8812au and rtl8812bu.

Answer (score 1):

After countless tries to get it to work, I finally downgraded to Xubuntu 20.04.6 LTS and added drivers rtl8812bu (from github).
To make it all work I also did
sudo apt install git dkms
and sudo ./deploy.sh (which was deploy script for the drivers).
For now it all works, finally, tho who knows for how long since it's again rather old Xubuntu.

Comment: FYI:  If you installed with Xubuntu 20.04.6 (*or 20.04.5 if .6 media was never created due to looming EOL*) you'll be using the HWE kernel stack from 20.04 which is the GA kernel stack from 22.04 (ie. 5.15 kernel), so I'd likely try Xubuntu 22.04 or 22.04.1 install media and see if it works there, giving you a fully-supported system; rather than you HWE stack 22.04 earlier which used 6.2 kernel.  Well done for working out a solution though (*even if not ideal*).  https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack

Comment: Thanks appreciate it, gonna give it a try.